# Sending a file to multiple servers

Tags: server

I'm working on a web project(built with the .Net framework) on a remote windows server, and this project is connected to a database my `SQL server management studio`, now on multiple other remote windows servers exist the same web project linked to the same database, now I change a page's code in my project or add/remove a `table` or `stored procedure` in my database, is there a way(or an already existing software) which will my to deploy the changes that I made to all the others(or to choose multiple servers if I don't want to deploy the changes to all of them)?

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is, can you elaborate? Making a change to the DB (adding/removing a table, in your example) is just that -- a change to the _database_. Any connected client will have those changes upon querying (and you've stated that they're all "linked" to the same database). Are you asking how to force other instances of the application to re-query when a change is made?

Comment: Sorry, hitting the character limit here. I also see that you're mentioning code itself. Is the question, then, relating _only_ to code and the DB stuff you've listed as examples will strictly exist in code (via migrations, etc.)? If so, I'd assume the question is more related to deploying code to all servers. In that case, there are loads of solutions. One example would be Jenkins, where you script out what happens upon pushing code to a repo. Pipeline software will allow you to build/deploy your software to your liking, even allowing you to individually deploy to servers of your choosing.

Comment: In order to provide a more relevant answer, I would like more information. Specifically, what technologies are you using? What lanuage is the "code" written in? What runtime do they use? I suspect something like MVC, where the database schema is largely determined by C# code, may be in play. What database software and authoring tools are you using? Something may even be available to integrate with your IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it were me, I would stand up a git server somewhere (cloud or local vm), make a branch called something like `Prod` or `Stable`, and create a script (powershell if the servers are windows, bash on anything else) on a nightly or hourly job to pull from that branch. Only push to that branch after testing thoroughly. If your code requires compilation, you have the choice to compile once before committing (in which case you're probably going to commit to `releases`), or on each endpoint after the pull. I would have the script that does the pull also compile and restart the service (only if there was something new in the pull).

Answer (score 2):

You can probably achieve this by following two things :

1. Create a separate publishing profile for each server.
2. Use git/vsts branches to keep the code separate. (as suggested by @memtha).

Let's say you have total 6 servers and two branches A and B. So, you'll have to create 6 publishing profiles. Then, you can choose which branch to deploy where. e.g. you can deploy branch B on server 1,3 and 4.

Answer (score 1):

For the codebase you could use Git Hooks.

https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa

And for the database, maybe you could use migrations or something similar. You will need to provide more info about your database, do you store your database across multiple servers etc.

Answer (score 1):

If the same web project is connecting to the same database and the database changes, I suspect you would need to update all the web apps to ensure the database changes don't break any of the apps and to keep all the apps updated to prevent any being left behind.

You should look at using Azure Devops to build and deploy your apps and update the database.

If you use Entity Framework, you can run the migrations on startup and have the application update the database when deployed manually or automatically using devops.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the software updated in multiple server you could use Git with hooks, post-receive hook is what you need.

The idea is to use one server as your Remote Repository and here configure the post-receive hook to update the codebase in the same server and the others.